# vuejs loop over in data results not on how many fields i have

Tags: laravel, vue.js

`v-for` is iterating over on my fields not to the data that i selected, example i have 3 fields in my database(name,email,username) it will loop 3 times

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDqUS.jpg)

Profile.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Profile</h3>
        <user-profile v-for="user in users" :user="user" :key="user.id"></user-profile>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import UserProfile from '../partials/UserProfile.vue'
    import User from '../models/User'
    import Form from '../core/Form'

    export default {
        components: {
            UserProfile
        },
        data() {
            return {
                users: [
                    users:[],
                ],
            }
        },
        created() {
            axios.get('/user/profile').then(res => this.users = res);
        }
    };
</script>
```

UserProfile.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12" method="POST" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" v-model="form.name" class="validate" autofocus>
                <label for="name" class="active">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" v-model="form.email" class="validate" autofocus>
                <label for="email" class="active">Email</label>
            </div>

            <div class="right-align">
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Update
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Form from '../core/Form'

    export default {
        props: ['user'],
        data() {
            return {
                form: new Form({
                    name: this.user.name,
                })
            }
        },
        computed: {
            //
        },
        mounted() {

        },
        methods: {
            //
            onSubmit() {
                axios.post('/user/update', {
                    name: this.user.name
                })
                    .then(console.log('yeahh'))
                    .catch(console.log('failed'))
            }
        }

    };
</script>
```

Comment: Is that meant to only be one user in the `users` array? Also, where is the `user.id` coming from?

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit it before posting, its edited now its users:[] not users:[{name:'Axel Mhar'}]

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(this.users);` in your `created()` method (after the line where you get your users).

Comment: im getting <code>[__ob__: Observer] </code> oops sorry im not used in stackoverflow i dont know how to wrap this in code format

Comment: @AxelMhar you have to click to open that.  You use backticks for code in comments.  Use the Vue dev tools extension and teach yourself how to use the developer console.  Learning how to debug should be #1 priority.

Answer (score 0):

Your `users` inside Data looks wrong.
Here is an edited version

#### Profile

```
<script>
  import UserProfile from '../partials/UserProfile.vue'
  import User from '../models/User'
  import Form from '../core/Form'

  export default {
      components: {
        UserProfile
      },
      data() {
        return {
            users: [ 
              {
                name: 'FirstName LastName',
                email: 'firstname.lastname@gmail.com'
              }
            ],
        }
      },
      created() {
        // User.all(users => this.users = users)
      }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: yeah sorry its users:[], im getting all the data in the database, but why v-for is looping on how many fields i have not on the data i want to get example im getting the currently logged in user it should only loop once

Comment: looks like in your new created call you are fetching data for only one user now. Sorry but you keep changing several time your example so it is hard to help you with a changing code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only returning the currently logged in user, you'll have to edit your `Profile` component a bit:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Profile</h3>
        <user-profile :user="user" :key="user.id"></user-profile>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import UserProfile from '../partials/UserProfile.vue'
    import User from '../models/User'
    import Form from '../core/Form'

    export default {
        components: {
            UserProfile
        },
        data() {
            return {
                user: {},
            }
        },
        created() {
            axios.get('/user/profile').then(res => this.user = res);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: im getting Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null" i cant read user.id id thats why it throws that error

Comment: @AxelMhar Can you show the controller method for the route?

Comment: `

public function show()
    {
     return auth()->user();
    }

`
i cant format it in code but im returning the currently logged user

Comment: @AxelMhar The reason it's looping through the attributes is because you're only returning one user. I'm assuming that you're going to be returning more than one in the future or is it always just going to be the currently auth user?

Comment: no, its personal profile settings, i just want to return the current user logged in data and populate the fields in form, make all the data reactive

Comment: @AxelMhar In that case you don't want to be using `v-for` since you won't have an array of users. I've updated my answer.